# When articulating this sentence, where do you have a pause?

Tags: pronunciation

> I could organize it that someone could win a round-trip air ticket.
>
> Paul put it that he was going to have to make a choice.

---

In my case, as a second language learner, I put the pause between **it** and **that.**
How about for the native speakers??

Comment: What does *condent* mean in your first example sentence? Maybe a typo for *confident*?

Comment: yope, I've changed the example.

Comment: No pauses in these sentences. A pause between *it* and *that* makes it sound unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a *syntactic* pause where the OP has indicated, after the main independent clause, to demarcate where the subordinate clause begins. This is not a "rhetorical" pause.

Answer (score 0):

[Sentence 1](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1TsEzXFF8Sg)

[Sentence 2](http://vocaroo.com/i/s14VI2XSKefN)

No discernible pause necessary. (British English). My voice.

Comment: You're speaking naturally yet fairly quickly. Though you may think the pause is not discernible, it is.  It's a relative duration: the very brief "parsing-rhythm" pause between each of the words *Paul..put..it* and  *that..he..was* is considerably shorter than the syntactic pause between "it" and "that", and the syntactic boundary is further corroborated by the intonational contours.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth out your sentences.

I could organize the contest so that someone could win a round-trip air ticket.
Paul put the statement to me that he'll have to make a choice.

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence examples the "***it***" creates a natural pause, especially in the first sentence, consider

> I could organize **it** that someone could win a round-trip air ticket.

versus

> I could organize that someone could win a round-trip air ticket.